# Passing v8 options to forever with nodejs

Tags: node.js, forever

So I use forever with nodejs to keep my servers up.  I need to pass in some v8 options.  I can do this via nodejs command line, but how I can do this with forever?

Answer (score 46):

```
forever start -c "node --harmony" app.js
```

Comment: Omit "start" if you want to watch a file, e.g. `forever -c "node --harmony" -w app.js`

Comment: Great, finally someone with a working tip over here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

specify a shell script instead.
let the script **callnode.sh** contain the line

```
node --debug $1 $2 $3
```

you may call it from forever like this:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');
forever.start(['./callnode.sh', 'your_process.js', {});
```

or use the forever cli option -c

Comment: How does this -c option work then? I've tried: forever start -c "node --harmony" app.js but it doesn't start, also without quotes

Comment: "doesn't start" means what?